# Make Title Error

Tags: titles

I'm new as a user of LaTeX and my doubt might seem fool, but here I go. I'm facing the following error message after running my script:

> "Package inputenc Error: Unicode character (U+000B)(inputenc) not set
> up for use with LaTeX. \maketitle".

Bellow I'm sending the script used:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

%opening
\title{Autonomous mobile robot: thermal modellingInternship X-21}
\author{Marcelo Bruno Chaves Franco}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    
- What are the main heat sources an where are they located?
- For a specific ambient temperature, what is the maximum temperature inside the vehicle?
- What are the forced convection parameters required?

\end{abstract}

\section{}

\end{document}
```

Why I cannot make the title? I've done exactly what the prepared model was showing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a character before the word _thermal_ and again before the word _Internship_ that is likely causing the issue. If what you want is a new line, use \\ instead.

Comment: Unicode character 000B is a "vertical tabulator".  I don't know where this might be used these days; it was relevant in "the old days" with line printers.  Just delete it; I see that's what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

When I compile this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\title{Autonomous mobile robot: thermal modelling Internship X-21} \author{Marcelo Bruno Chaves Franco}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}

    What are the main heat sources an where are they located?
    For a specific ambient temperature, what is the maximum temperature inside the vehicle?
    What are the forced convection parameters required?

\end{abstract}
\section{}
\end{document}
```

I get this:

[image]

But I had to eliminate two strange characters from the tile in order that this works.